# would a "Refresh" button be an appropriate use case for forceUpdate()?

Tags: reactjs

> "Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only
> read from this.props and this.state in render()."

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

However, I think I may have a scenario where forceUpdate() seems appropriate.

I have a requirement to add a "Refresh" button on a component.  Clicking the button should do a full refresh of the component.  I could implement this by toggling a custom "refresh" property on state, but that seems like overkill for this particular scenario when calling forceUpdate() seems like a simple, streamlined approach appropriate for the specific scenario at hand.  Do you agree with my assessment on this one?

Comment: What would refreshing the component do if props/state have not changed? In other words, what do you expect to "refresh"?

Comment: why would you need a refresh? what are you trying to accomplish through the fresh?

Comment: I'm working on a migration from an old school web app.  the business analysts are really picky about bringing everything over as closely as possible.  this particular component displays the details of various backend jobs.  the page doesn't use a sophisticated pub/sub design to monitor/refresh the latest status of the jobs to the page so a refresh button is used instead.

Comment: But where are those job status's coming from? Are they retrieved by an API call? Unless they're set as like global variables somewhere, and not fetched by your react code, `forceUpdate` will not help. You'll just need to re-call your API endpoint.

Comment: the data is retrieved through a nested component.  I just confirmed that the nested component gets triggered/re-rendered via forceUpdate() so it seems like forceUpdate() accomplishes the refresh goal in the most straightforward way